# How to specify a sheet to determine 'lastrow'?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to determine 'lastrow' of the sheet that the macro is being run on.

I am working with two sheets. Sheet1 has about 150 rows of data and Sheet 2 only has two.

I expected that when I selected Sheet2 and assigned lastrow that it would take the count of rows from Sheet2, instead it is storing the row count from sheet1.

```
sub row_count()
dim lastrow as long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

if lastrow = 150 then
    with sheets("sheet2")
        .select
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        msgbox lastrow '<----- Always returns the value of sheet1 instead of sheet2.
    end with

end sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row` should be `Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row` if you want it to be on sheet2

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile, please post actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [With block](http://www.homeandlearn.org/with_end_with.html), which means the program sees anything between 'With' and 'End With' as being prefixed by whatever you put after the keyword 'With', so to modify your code in place for sheet2 only:

```
Sub row_count()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow = 150 Then
    With Sheets("sheet2")
    ' .Select = Sheets("sheet2").Select
    .Select
    ' .Range = Sheets("sheet2").Range
    lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow
End With

End Sub
```

If you want the code to run on the currently visible sheet you should change it to use the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174742(v=office.11).aspx) property:

```
Sub row_count()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow = 150 Then
    With ActiveSheet ' use the currently visible sheet
    .Select
    lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow
End With

End Sub
```

However, there are some ways to improve this code: for flexibility you could pass the worksheet as a [parameter](http://www.homeandlearn.org/passing_values_to_a_sub.html). Also, your [End](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx) function might return the first used row if there is already data in the last used row (it's the same as clicking in the last row and pressing Ctrl & the up arrow, so you should start in a cell below that). Lastly, you do not need to select the sheet to get the last row:

```
Sub GetRowCounts()

row_count Sheets("sheet1")
row_count Sheets("sheet2")

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub row_count(ws As Worksheet)

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox lastrow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these examples are the easiest to follow.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Keep an open mind though, there are lots of ways to do this same kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If this statement...

```
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

... really always returns the last row of Sheet1 instead of last row of Sheet2, then that is because you are looking at your Workbook open at Sheet1 all the time.

Whenever you have a Range or Cells statement like the above ( Range(...) ) without an explicit reference to a Worksheet, then ActiveSheet is what it is referenced to.

So to avoid that, this is what you do:

```
Dim Sht_1 as Worksheet
Dim Sht_2 as Worksheet
Dim Sht_1_Lastrow as Long
Dim Sht_2_Lastrow as Long

Set Sht_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set Sht_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

Sht_1_Lastrow = Sht_1.Range("A" & Sht_1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sht_2_Lastrow = Sht_2.Range("A" & Sht_2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
Sht_1_Lastrow = Sht_1.Cells(Sht_1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sht_2_Lastrow = Sht_2.Cells(Sht_2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Above code block highlights the difference that makes a `LastRow` Variable explicitly tied to a certain Worksheet...

This way your problem cannot happen...